# How to add control to Grid in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the Xml code:

```
        <**Grid Name="myGrid"** Background="#FFE9F4F8" Margin="0,4" ShowGridLines="False"  >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Character"/>

            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"   x:Name="comboBoxChar">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="blue 1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="blue 2"/>
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=behaviorName}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

            <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" x:Name="comboBoxBehavior" ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=comboList}" Visibility="{Binding Path=visible}"/>


        </Grid>
    **</DataTemplate>**
```

I want to add some control(textBox,for example) to this Grid (named "myGrid") in c# code.
How to do this?

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate1" x:Name="dataTemplate1" >

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txt.Width = 200;
txt.Height = 100;
myGrid.Children.Add(txt) ;
```

Comment: don't working...   public MainWindow()
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = "Hi";
            myGrid.Children.Add(tb);

        }

Comment: could you please remove your grid definition and try

Comment: this is not working... maby beause the Grid is in DataTemplate?

Comment: yes it should not be inside a datatemplate, it should be the parent

Comment: if I want to leave the code like that, there some way to solve this problem?